# How to get the build date of a Debian system?

Tags: linux, debian

What I have here is a powerpc device with pretty ancient Debian installed on it.

It's identifiable as Lenny derivative: `/etc/issue` mentions `Debian GNU/Linux 5.0`. There are some vendor-specific packages.

Which corners of the system I could use to extract the *build* date of the distribution? I'm not interested in the date of installation.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. Why do you need it? Would something like knowing the `gcc` version be enough?

Comment: @terdon, I need to know which version of cron is there (but that's perhaps for another question). There's no `gcc` on the system; `strings /lib/libgcc_s.so.1` has a symbol `GCC_4.3.0`. There's `gdb`, however it could be vendor-built.

Comment: I am asking because this sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I can't imagine why the build date would ever be relevant. If you want to know the `cron` version, then that's what you should be asking. Isn't `dpkg -l cron` enough?

Comment: Well, I just thought that this could become a good general question not tied to my today's needs in any way. People constantly look for way to determine the installation date, for example. You're right, that's a classic XY problem; but if viewed from Q&A community contribution angle -- that's just a poorly motivated general question. And we all know that good questions don't need rigorous motivation at all.

Comment: @terdon the build date would be relevant during investigations of history of a particular distro, especially if it's got a rich history *(especially if it's a legal investigation)*. Meaning several changes of vendor ownership (with corresponding rounds of code changes) after the initial release by the Debian community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each package that compiles with the Debian policy contains a changelog file in `/usr/share/doc/PACKAGE-NAME/changelog.Debian`. The file may be called `changelog.gz` if the package is built from a native Debian source. The latest entry in the changelog is supposed to be the time the package was finalized, i.e. it's after the last change to the package source and before the time the package was built.

The **timestamp on compilation outputs** (native executables, libraries, bytecode, etc.) will be the time at which they were built. Inasmuch as the build date of a system exists, this is it. It is, of course, different for every package — a Debian system is not built in one go. (Well, it would be theoretically possible, but it would take a very long time.)

If some `.deb` files are present in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, their modification time will give an upper bound on their build time.

The modification time of directories and the inode change times (`ls -lc`) give a lower bound on the age of the files involved. Logs may be available in `/var/log/dpkg.log*` and `/var/log/apt`. (Maybe not if the distribution is too ancient, I don't remember whether these already existed in lenny.) But this is all installation-time or post-installation.

In a comment, you mention a legal investigation. All these timestamps can be easily faked, so they're only useful if the administrator of the system is not suspected of tampering with them.

Answer (score 2):

Check build date of installed software, eg aptitude. This won't work if the software had a security upgrade, but otherwise the earlist compilation time from of a bunch of packages that do report their compile times would give you some idea. My system is Debian 7.6 (wheezy). Here are some examples from my machine.

#### aptitude

```
faheem@orwell:~$ aptitude --version
aptitude 0.6.8.2 compiled at Nov  7 2012 07:08:03
Compiler: g++ 4.7.2
Compiled against:
  apt version 4.12.0
  NCurses version 5.9
  libsigc++ version: 2.2.10
  Ept support enabled.
  Gtk+ support disabled.
  Qt support disabled.

Current library versions:
  NCurses version: ncurses 5.9.20110404
  cwidget version: 0.5.16
  Apt version: 4.12.0
```

#### apt-get

```
faheem@orwell:~$ apt-get --version
apt 0.9.7.9 for amd64 compiled on Oct  8 2014 10:25:29
Supported modules:
*Ver: Standard .deb
*Pkg:  Debian dpkg interface (Priority 30)
 Pkg:  Debian APT solver interface (Priority -1000)
 S.L: 'deb' Standard Debian binary tree
 S.L: 'deb-src' Standard Debian source tree
 Idx: Debian Source Index
 Idx: Debian Package Index
 Idx: Debian Translation Index
 Idx: Debian dpkg status file
 Idx: EDSP scenario file
```

#### slrn

```
faheem@orwell:~$ slrn --version
slrn 1.0.1
S-Lang Library Version: 2.2.4
Compiled on: Feb 10 2014 20:58:07
Operating System: Linux

COMPILE TIME OPTIONS:
 Backends: +nntp +slrnpull +spool
 External programs / libs: +canlock +inews +ssl +uudeview +iconv
 Features: +decoding +emphasized_text +end_of_thread +fake_refs +gen_msgid
    -grouplens -msgid_cache +piping +rnlock +spoilers -strict_from
 Using 64 bit integers for article numbers.

DEFAULTS:
 Default server object:     nntp
 Default posting mechanism: nntp
```

#### ssh

```
faheem@orwell:~$ ssh -v
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

#### vim

```
faheem@orwell:~$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 10 2013 02:28:47)
```

#### openssl

```
faheem@orwell:~$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

#### nano

```
faheem@orwell:~$ nano --version
GNU nano version 2.2.6 (compiled 21:40:01, Jun 22 2012)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Exactly what I needed. Only thought about querying gcc compile options.

Comment: `openssl version` independently too. Also there's no `slrn` program on this system, so I'd move it to the end. Also `vim --version`.

Comment: This only shows the date when the packages were compiled, not the date when the distribution itself was. For example, note that your dates range from 2012 to 2014. Even so, all it takes is for you to have upgraded aptitude once and even that oldest date is wrong.

Comment: @terdon true. the earliest compile time from this group only gives an upper bound for the build time of the distribution. And even this assumes that the packages are all rebuilt for the release, which may not be the case. Not a terribly precise metric, agreed. Of course, the question itself is not terribly precise. Parts of a given stable Debian distribution are upgraded from time to time, so what does build date of the distribution mean, exactly? The date of the earliest (.0) version, (assuming there is such a thing)?

Comment: What about build timestamps in the `binutils` package? I think that it's possible to extract them from the `-g` debug data, and `binutils` rarely change.

Comment: @ulidtko i'm not sure how one would get timestamps from binutils.

Answer (score 0):

from https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2013/05/msg01045.html

> ~# uname -a
> Linux wheezy 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> ~# ls -l /boot/vm*
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2833376 May 15 23:58 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
> ~#
>
> There is no date in the uname output anymore, which I could compare to
> the kernel image file's timestamp.

You are now supposed to compare the Debian package version reported
by uname (3.2.41-2 in the example above) against the one currently
installed (e.g. using dpkg -l). /proc/version still reports the build
time for me, though.

> doesn't sound convincing to me. As an administrator, I couldn't care
> less what source was used to build the kernel package installed.

As the source package used to build the kernel uniquely identifies the
kernel, you should only care about the source package version?

===

imo it would suck if centos/rhel did away with build date in uname...